# 500 Internal Server error from mod_wsgi and django rest

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, mod-wsgi

I have looked at every similar question about this and still can't figure out what's wrong. I'm try to set up a python REST service on my VPS alongside my wordpress site. I can get a "Hello world" wsgi file to run no problem, but when I point to my django rest wsgi file, I get a 500 server error.

My wordpress site is in `/var/www/html/mysite/public_html`, and the rest service is in /var/www/html/mysite/myrest. www-data has ownership of everything in the mysite folder. I've installed all dependencies, and started the project with `python manage.py runserver` just to make sure it's not missing anything.

This is my wsgi file.

```
import os
import sys
import site

site.addsitedir('/var/www/html/mysite/myrest/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

sys.path.append('/var/www/html/mysite/myrest')

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/var/www/html/mysite/.python-egg'

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Before it didn't have the `site.addsitedir` stuff, that got added as I tried different solutions.

There's some weird stuff going on in the apache logs, but I couldn't make sense of it.

```
[Sun Feb 19 20:39:33.697146 2017] [core:notice] [pid 26048] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Feb 19 20:41:30.804083 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26048] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Feb 19 20:41:31.707014 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 26721] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.11.
[Sun Feb 19 20:41:31.707037 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 26721] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12.
[Sun Feb 19 20:41:31.709784 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26721] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Feb 19 20:41:31.709801 2017] [core:notice] [pid 26721] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

I'm pulling my hair out. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html for the correct way of setting up a Python virtual environment with mod_wsgi. Also temporarily enable ``DEBUG=True`` in Django settings file, or configure Django to log exceptions to ``stdout`` stream so you can see what error it is that your Django application code is generating when return the 500.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, if that was the problem, there was still more to fix.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my settings.py file. I managed to debug it by putting

```
import django
django.setup()
```

in various places throughout settings.py.